# inquiry regarding clientid retrieval with _ga cookie disabled

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

We have observed that approximately 20% of our data fails to be uploaded to GA4 over a span of two weeks via the server-side API. Upon investigation, we suspect that the discrepancy in the GA4 order reports compared to our actual transaction data is due to users disabling the _ga cookie, which seemingly impacts our ability to accurately transmit essential data, including the clientID, from the server side to GA4.

Given the critical nature of accurate data reporting for our operations, we would greatly appreciate anyone's guidance on the following questions:

1. When the _ga cookie is disabled by users, what alternative methods or best practices does Google Analytics recommend for retrieving or generating a clientID on the server side?
2. Are there specific parameters or configurations within the server-side API that we should implement to mitigate the impact of disabled _ga cookies on data accuracy?
3. Can you provide any insights or recommendations on how to ensure the integrity of order reporting in GA4, particularly in scenarios where browser restrictions affect cookie tracking?

Thanks!